# Programmatically generate APNS certificate

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to programmatically generate the Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) certificate? I'd like to write a script that automatically renews our APNS certificate every year by creating a new one and uploading it to our server.

Comment: very interesting question, even I would want to get an answer if its possible.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/pem

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use some automation tools to do it

If we look at APNS certificate generation guide https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/how-to-create-apns-certificate - we can see that we need some automation for Web and Desktop tasks

For Web we can use [Selenium IDE](https://selenium2.ru/docs/selenium-ide.html). For Desktop we can use [Apple Automator](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/welcome/mac)

I believe we can write scripts for both and then combine into single bash run script

Also, there is a [fastlane pem generator](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/pem/) that also can be used for such purpose

I recommend to think twice before start doing it - it's only need to be done once per year, so maybe it's faster to do so manually than spend time for building such a script :)

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario you may no longer need to re-generate certificates every year if your server supports APNS token-based authentication with .p8 token files:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token-based_connection_to_apns